# What determines which of a DHCP Relay Agent's IP addresses are attached to relayed requests?

Tags: dhcp, vlan

I have a vlan with multiple IPs set, and a helper-address:

```
vlan 15
 ip helper-address 172.17.1.11
 ip address 172.17.5.254 255.255.255.0
 ip address 172.17.51.254 255.255.254.0
```

All relayed requests have 172.17.5.254 set as the RelayAgentIP.  How can I change this behavior so the other IP is sent instead?  Removing the first IP would cause a routing problem for clients still on that subnet, so I'd prefer not to do that.

This is a HP Procurve 5400zl switch.

Comment: You haven't told us what kind of switch/router this syntax originates from. It's not Cisco for sure. Please be more specific.

Comment: are  you in the process of renumbering this subnet? Else not sure why you would have to 2  L3 networks on the same port.  I am not familiar with the procurve, but see if there is an option to specify one as a secondary

Comment: I've looked at our HP switches, and there are no syntax to set a secondary IP on them. Perhaps HP switches looks at the configuration line-by-line, and then picks the first IP address. Besides that, how on earth do you have this functioning with a default gateway? Are you using static routes?

Comment: @pauska If those hosts on each Subnet need to communicate directly with each other, it should work ok.  assuming the procurve can route. And if they need to talk to each other and the procurve can hairpin, it should still work. but not sure why you would do it.

Comment: The reason I'm doing this is because 172.17.5.1/24 doesn't have enough addresses for the number of clients that are connecting.  My original plan was to just change it to 172.17.5.1/23 and then expand the dhcp scope accordingly, but apparently windows dhcp doesn't allow you to change the subnet mask once the scope has been created.  Also, I don't think the windows dhcp server would be 'smart' enough to issue leases correctly if I were to just create another scope as 172.17.6.1/24...

Comment: well the problem with 172.17.5.0/23 is that it isn't a valid subnet, since it would need to fall on a bit boundary   172.17.4.0/23, and 172.17.6.0/23 are both valid /23's  Perhaps that is why windows wouldn't let you resize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, any traffic sourced from an interface (in your case the VLAN interface) will be sourced from the primary ip address of the interface. So if you want the DHCP requests to be sourced from 172.17.51.254 then you need to make that the primary ip address for the VLAN interface.

Comment: Makes sense.  So I guess the real question is what determines which address is the primary one for a vlan?

Comment: My guess is that it is switch dependent.  Most switches I've dealt with don't allow you to set 2 ip addresses, without making the others secondary

Comment: My guess would be that the first ip address you assign is the primary ip address and all other ip addresses are secondary addresses, just like with a physical interface.